# Grails Remote Function onSuccess vs onComplete

Tags: jquery, ajax, grails, grails-2.0

I have the following Grails code:

```
${remoteFunction(controller: 'myController', 
                     action: 'myMethod',
                     params: 'params',
                  onSuccess: 'mySuccessMethod(data);',
                 onComplete: 'myCompleteMethod();',
                     update: 'divName')};
```

I would expect:

- `mySuccessMethod()` and `myCompleteMethod()` to each get called once when the Ajax call completes

What I get is

- `mySuccessMethod()` is called once **immediately**
- When the Ajax call (eventually) completes

  - `mySuccessMethod()` is called a **second time**
  - `myCompleteMethod()` is called (once).

In looking up this problem, the Ajax recommendation was to use `onsuccess`, but the implementation (i.e. when it is invoked) seems different in Grails.

Can someone please explain this.

- Why is `mySuccessMethod()` called twice?
- Does this mean that we should be using `onComplete` rather than `onSuccess`, at least in Grails?

(Edited: Information below added as a response to request for additional information.)

The generated HTML from the remoteFunction() call is as follows (I added CR and spaces for readability):

```
jQuery.ajax({type:'POST',data:paramString,
                 url:'/<appname>/myController/myMethod',
                 success:function(data,textStatus){
                     jQuery('#divName').html(data);
                     mySuccessMethod(data);;
                 },
                 error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){
                 },
                 complete:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus){
                     myCompleteMethod();
                 }
             });;
```

The console log from mySuccessMethod has the following for data:

- First call:

  ```
  <div class="loading-content"/>
  ```
- Second call:

  ```
  <The actual expected response>
  ```

Thanks.

Comment: @dmahapatro: I do not understand your comment.  What do you mean by co-relate?  This is not a try/catch/finally issue.  It is a Grails-wrapped jQuery/Ajax call.

Comment: it shouldn't get called twice from Grails `remoteFunction`. Something else is happening on the page. Can you post the generated HTML from the `remoteFunction` call?

Comment: @aldrin: I added the generated HTML above.  Thanks.

Comment: thanks for that. generated code looks just fine. surely something else in the page is calling that method?

Comment: @aldrin: Thank you very much.  Your question helped me find the cause.  When I saw the data from the First call above, it made me realize that the class "loading-content" was a CSS class internal to our project.  It turns out that someone had added code to intercept Ajax calls, and was injecting this response as an interim process to display a spinner.
Given that the problem landed up being internal to the project I am working on, how should I deal with this Stack Overflow question?  Answer it myself?  Close the question as invalid?  Do you want to answer it and I will accept that? Thx again.

Comment: @aldrin Or should I accept Fahimeh's answer below?  I am not sure what the Stack Overflow etiquette is in a case like this.

Comment: it is totally acceptable to answer your own question. glad you able to sort out the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`onComplete` will call every time at the end of each ajax call, even it is succeed or failed or any updates.  But `onSuccess` is called when it is successful. It means that you can't use `onComplete` instead of `onSuccess`

Note that - as of jQuery 1.5 - the underlying ajax method names have been changed:

- `success()` is now `done()`
- `error()` is now `fail()`
- `complete()` is now `always()`

With Grails 3 jQuery.ajax now has to be used directly, so these new names are important.

Comment: The behaviour you describe here is what the jQuery Ajax code says.  However that is not the behaviour that I saw in Grails.  That is the problem I describe above.  The onSuccess was called immediately before it completed successfully, and was called _again_ when completed successfully.  So I cannot use onSuccess.  My question is why?

Comment: My answer still works for your second question. If you use onComplete, it will call after any updates and I guess it's not your target.

Comment: I agree with what you said, but the problem is that that is not the behaviour I described above.  Why was onSuccess called twice, once even before it had even completed successfully?  How do I get around that?

Comment: I marked this solution as correct because it is, and the actual problem was in my own project.  Please see the above for the discussion with @aldrin.  Thanks to all who commented.